# Как выгрузить с .txt в Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Мне нужно выгрузить с файла email.txt в базу Mysql

файл email.txt выглядит так:

```
maxim@gmail.com
vlad@gmail.com
stas@gmail.com
```

и так более тысячи емайлов

Это все нужно загрузить в базу mysql

в таблицу user которая имеет такие столбцы id и email

И нужно чтоб в каждом столбце было как на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если файл содержит только email, как правильно соотнести email и user?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для начала сделайте автоинкриментирование поля id в базе данных.
Следующим шагом с помощью функции `fopen('#имя файла','#способ работы')` переберите все строчки в файлике с помощью функции `fread()`. Если у вас находятся в файле только e-mail, то нужно просто приконнектиться к бд с помощью функции `mysqli_connect('#ip-адрес базы данных', '#имя_пользователя', '#ваш_пароль','#имя базы данных')`.Далее с помощью элементарного запроса функции `mysqli_query()` заносите данные в бд . Надеюсь объяснил довольно доходчиво, если что-то будет непонятно - пишите.

Например так:
`$connection = mysqli_connect($config['db']['server'], $config['db']['username'],$config['db']['password'], $config['db']['name']);
$categories_q = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO`#имя бд`VALUES(#тут будет ваша переменная с e-mail)");`

P.S $config - это массивчик с вашими пользовательскими настройками)

Comment: fopen('#имя файла','#способ работы') не понял для чего это ? И как это делать ?

Comment: А как вы догадались, что спрашивающий на php пишет ? И кстати если работа разовая проще весь файл прогнать через режим "text to DDL" на сайте sqlfiddle.com и получить готовый набор команд insert который тупо выполнить в консоли mysql